# Jquery creating multiple divs with specific height and colors

Tags: jquery, html

I want to create **9*9** `divs` in my html page using Jquery, also I'd like to ask if it's possible to create them with a specific height (100px) and background color depending on the column, (e.g. column 1 yellow color, column 2 red etc), will the ids of the divs be unique?

Comment: Yes Id's must be unique

Comment: The `id`s will be unique if you make them unique (manually, or via JavaScript/jQuery). Is that the question you're asking, or is the question how to create these random div elements?

Answer (score 0):

Check this one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
          $(".wrapper").append("<div id=" + i + "" + j + " class='box col" + j + "'>")
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    .wrapper {
      width: 920px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    .box {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      float: left;
      margin: 1px;
    }
    
    .col1 {
      background: yellow;
    }
    
    .col2 {
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While it's obvious to more experienced programmers, some people will have trouble understanding some parts of this. Actually _explain_ your answer, instead of just posting code

Answer (score 0):

you can create them like this:

```
for(var cntx = 0;cntx < 9;cntx ++){
   $("#containerDiv").append("<div class='divRow'>");
   for(var cnty = 0;cnty < 9;cnty ++){
       var mydiv = "<div class='mydiv' style='height: 100px; background: red; display: inline-block;' id='"; 
       mydiv += #divID
       mydiv += "'>";
       mydiv += #contetn for div contx * 9 + conty
       mydiv += "</div>;
       $("#containerDiv").append(mydiv);
   }
   $("#containerDiv").append("</div>");

}
```

in style parameter you can set any css attribute for each element you want!

Comment: You should generate each `div` with `$(document.createElement('div')).addClass('mydiv').css(...).prop('id', ...)` instead of string concatenation which is just horrible

Comment: the only problem is Danny is a newbie so its easer for him to handle!;)

Comment: Then it's even more important that you demonstrate the correct way of doing things, as per my first comment

Answer (score 0):

Here is code:
Edit:More simpler way using JavaScript only

```html
<html>
<head>
 <style>
      .row {
          width: 50%;
          text-align: center;
          margin-top: 1px;
          color: #f0f0f0;
      }
      .abc0 {
          background: #303
      }
      .abc1 {
          background: #108
      }
      .abc2 {
          background: #801
      }
      .abc3 {
          background: #306
      }
      .abc4 {
          background: #702
      }
      .abc5 {
          background: #207
      }
      .abc6 {
          background: #603
      }
      .abc7 {
          background: #405
      }
      .abc8 {
          background: #504
      }
  </style>
</head>
  
<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var string = '';
            for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                string += "<div class='row abc" + j + "'>" + j + "</div>";
            document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = string;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You just have to change the background colors and data it contains in div.